# Twitter account management for linux - mass unfollow based on filter

Tags: twitter

I got my twitter account hacked, and thousands of spam tweets with links to dodgy websites posted, also I now follow thousands of accounts of absolute no interest to me.

While I managed to find tools that deletes mass tweets, I couldn't find something that works with unfollowing accounts based on filters.

I tried a bunch of website and I tried to [download tweet added](http://www.tweetadder.com/), 
but it wouldn't start on my Ubuntu.

Any ideas? tools? whether online or linux based... Regards